Asymptotic expansion using gamma functions and Stirling's formula
Question: obtain an expression for the $n$th term of an asymptotic expansion, valid as $ \lambda \to \infty$ for the integral
$$I(\lambda) = \int_0^1 t^{2\alpha}e^{-\lambda(t^2+t^3)} dt $$
where $ \alpha >-1/2 $. Also, obtain the first two terms of an asymptotic expansion, valid as $ \lambda \to\infty $ for the integral
$$I(\lambda) = \int_0^1 t^{2\alpha}e^{-\lambda(t^2-t^3)} dt $$
where $ -1/2<\alpha <0$.
(hint: use the gamma function and Stirling's formula).
What I've done: I've only tried the first part and got stuck. I tried to relate it to gamma functions, by simply letting $(t^2 + t^3) = u$. This looks appropriate because $(t^2 + t^3)$ is monotonic, but to change variables I would need to find the inverse of this function, which is quite nasty.
So, how shall I proceed? Any help is greatly appreciated!

I cannot see how the gamma function or Stirling's formula could help you. By Laplace's method,
$$
\int_0^1 {t^{2\alpha } {\rm e}^{ - \lambda (t^2 + t^3 )} {\rm d}t}  \sim\lambda^{ - \alpha  - 1/2} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\Gamma \bigg( {\frac{{n + 1}}{2} + \alpha } \bigg)\frac{{b_n  }}{{\lambda^{n/2} }}} 
$$
as $\lambda\to+\infty$, where
$$
b_n   = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{2\pi {\rm i}}}\oint_{(0 + )} {(1 + t)^{ - \frac{{n + 1}}{2} - \alpha } \frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{t^{n + 1} }}}  = \frac{{1}}{2}\binom{ - \frac{{n + 1}}{2} - \alpha }{n} = \frac{( - 1)^n}{2} \binom{\frac{{3n - 1}}{2} + \alpha }{n}.
$$
Further simplification yields
$$
\int_0^1 {t^{2\alpha } {\rm e}^{ - \lambda (t^2 + t^3 )} {\rm d}t}  \sim \frac{1}{2}\lambda^{ - \alpha  - 1/2} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\Gamma  \big( {\frac{{3n + 1}}{2} + \alpha } \big)}}{{n!}}\frac{( - 1)^n}{{\lambda^{n/2} }}} 
$$
as $\lambda\to+\infty$.
For the second integral, split it at $t=\frac{2}{3}$ and consider the two integrals separately.

Thank you! I guess you're right. Just applying Laplace'es method is more efficient as things are already in polynomials form.

You are welcome. Did you find my answer to your other question useful?

Absolutely yes! With your help I've been able to do all of them. Thank you so much!

For the question using Stirling's formula and gamma functions, I haven't studied Bernoulli numbers, but since I only need to find the first 2 terms, so I used your idea and got the first two terms explicitly :)

I've found a solution by ignoring the hint and simply using Laplace's method (thanks to Gary). I'll post it below:
Set $\phi(t)=-t^2-t^3$ and $f(t)=t^{2\alpha}$. The only absolute maximum is $t = 0$, so contributions of all orders come from this. Then the integral becomes (under asymptotic equivalence):
$\int_0^\epsilon t^{2\alpha} e^{-\lambda t^2}\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty (-\lambda t^3)^n/n!$
(exchange the order of summation and integration by Fubini, and then do integrals by the Gamma function)
= $\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty \Gamma(1/2+\alpha+3n/2) (-1)^n \lambda^{-1/2-n/2-\alpha} / 2n! $
For the second part, set $\phi(t) = t^3 - t^2$, then absolute maxima are t = 0 and 1, with t = 0 being a local maximum (but t = 1 is not). So, contributions of all orders will come from nbhds of these 2 points, but the l.o.t. is determined by the nbhd of t = 0. To find the first 2 terms, find the first 2 orders around t = 0 and the l.o.t around t = 1, then sum up.
